# Оформление перечня и инфинитивное предложение

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

«А порой нужно еще и откровенно что-то продавать или заключать сделки. И у тебя два выхода:

- Думать, что это «не твоё» и бежать в другие отделы, где ты будешь
  лишён бремени работы с клиентами.
- Просто научиться их правильно
  «готовить», овладев навыком переговоров. Уметь продавать, не
  продавая, и в некоторых компаниях    получать более 300 тысяч на
  продажах».

Правомерно ли в выделить последнее предложение как инфинитивное, чтобы не нагромождать предыдущее? Элементы списка в данном случае правильно писать с заглавной буквы или со строчной?

Answer (score 1):

> **Инфинитивное предложение** – это вид односоставных предложений, грамматической основой которого является сказуемое, выраженное
>   глаголом в независимой инфинитивной форме. Инфинитивное предложение
>   выражает необходимость или неизбежность того действия, о котором речь
>   в предложении: *Мне пора уходить. Быть грозе*.

(Это я как бы для себя, напоминание такое.)

Элементы списка именно здесь хорошо смотрятся с прописной - длинные предложения, а с тире, например, или с горошины был бы осложнён переход от пункта к пункту -

начало со строчной требует постановки точки с запятой в конце.

Что касается инфинитивного предложения, то, имхо, Вы его пересократили в предлагаемом варианте.

> Просто научиться их правильно «готовить», овладев навыком переговоров.
>   Уметь продавать, не продавая, и в некоторых компаниях получать более
>   300 тысяч на продажах.

Вы хотите изменить смысл своего предложения?

"Уметь продавать" - это совсем не то же самое, что "Уметь продавать, не продавая".

А про 300 тысяч на продажах - это не к нам вопрос.

Comment: По правилам между "переговоров" и "уметь" нужно поставить запятую, но я поставил то для наибольшей читабельности. Хотелось бы узнать, допустимо ли это? Вот и всё.

По поводу перечня: здесь стоит звёздочка, но в тексте стоит "буллет" или горошина, как вы её называли. В этом случае нельзя обойтись прописной буквой и точкой в конце пункта?

Comment: Можно так: *Просто научиться их правильно «готовить», овладев навыком переговоров: уметь продавать, не продавая.* Чем короче предложение, тем легче воспринимается. Так что точка - самое оно, но гляньте, как смотрится с двоеточием. А кто у нас тут допускает - не допускает? Хозяин - автор текста. Правила р. яз. не нарушены. Начальная прописная как раз и закрывается точкой. Строчная - точкой с запятой или запятой, если пунктов всего ничего (три-четыре, к примеру, но тогда каждый пункт - **одно отдельное предложение**).

Comment: А кстати, вас не смущает, что здесь у инфинитивного предложения совершенно нет никакого модального значения и это скорее просто однородные члены при обобщающем слове «два выхода» и нужно писать со строчной?

Comment: Про модальные значения - это не ко мне: я практик, редактор.

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант. "Уметь" относится и к "продавать", и к "получать". 
Тогда у вас два предложения, две основы: (1) научиться готовить, (2) уметь продавать и получать. Вы вправе поставить между ними точку, запятую, двоеточие, тире, союз — в зависимости от оттенков смысла и интонации, которые вы хотите передать.

Но скорее всего, "получать" — результат умения «готовить» и продавать. Тогда 
у вас три предложения, три основы: (1) научиться готовить, (2) уметь продавать (3) получать, причем по смыслу третье является результатом первого и второго. 
Вы не можете оставить "готовить" в одном предложении, а "продавать" и "получать" перенести в другое. Тогда я бы расставил знаки препинания так:

**Просто научиться их правильно «готовить», овладев навыком переговоров, уметь продавать, не продавая, — и (в результате) в некоторых компаниях получать более 300 тысяч на продажах.**

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, возможную постановку тире.

"Тире ставится между двумя сказуемыми и между двумя независимыми предложениями, если во втором из них содержится неожиданное присоединение или резкое противопоставление по отношению к первому" (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/158-tire)

Здесь ни первый случай, ни второй.